# Replacement of values in a data file

Tags: linux, fortran, octave, scilab

I'm trying to replace existing data values in a file. The file is intended for calculation of kinematic material hardening by a FEM-code. The text look like this for each element. I have a couple 100,000 of elements to modify:

---

```
13499         8        10         1         1                   0         0
1.500360e+08    1.451964e+07    3.728601e+08   -49529.937500   -1.930966e+07
4.499323e+06    4.427284e-03    2.107339e+06   -5.031084e+06    2.923746e+06
15250.131836   -1.833509e+06    1.992212e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.377865e+08    2.413883e+07    3.754904e+08    7.427730e+05   -2.500246e+07
2.964798e+06    4.422367e-03    1.855410e+06   -4.713138e+06    2.857730e+06
13224.164062   -2.054056e+06    1.624522e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.373486e+08    2.433924e+07    3.757281e+08   -4.595526e+06   -2.536434e+07
1.499050e+06    4.435852e-03    1.867437e+06   -4.746126e+06    2.878688e+06
-1.195839e+05   -2.081042e+06    1.472030e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.495412e+08    1.476622e+07    3.731083e+08   -5.636892e+06   -1.967031e+07
3.060086e+06    4.440636e-03    2.109059e+06   -5.047602e+06    2.938542e+06
-1.202835e+05   -1.849329e+06    1.847072e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.586573e+08    1.004740e+07    3.687111e+08   -6.710480e+05   -2.547207e+07
6.056666e+06    3.514634e-03    1.647607e+06   -3.689882e+06    2.042273e+06
  417.019592   -1.201436e+06    1.671364e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.461364e+08    2.007670e+07    3.712027e+08    66494.984375   -3.248405e+07
4.652704e+06    3.476992e-03    1.358743e+06   -3.303262e+06    1.944519e+06
 1658.200684   -1.316609e+06    1.339788e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.457837e+08    2.024077e+07    3.713914e+08   -5.707908e+06   -3.274767e+07
3.163598e+06    3.490632e-03    1.395223e+06   -3.361252e+06    1.966029e+06
-1.027537e+05   -1.351428e+06    1.227283e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
1.581765e+08    1.031220e+07    3.689273e+08   -6.650824e+06   -2.571731e+07
4.596290e+06    3.530744e-03    1.661256e+06   -3.721140e+06    2.059885e+06
-1.082121e+05   -1.219397e+06    1.555895e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
```

---

I want to change the text to this for all elements by the use of some smart commands, script etc. I'm using Linux but Windows 7 or Mac OS X can also be used if recommended.  I know the basics of FORTRAN, Scilab and Octave, but solutions outside of these environments are welcome.

---

```
13499         8        10         1         1                   0         0
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    2.107339e+06   -5.031084e+06    2.923746e+06
15250.131836   -1.833509e+06    1.992212e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    1.855410e+06   -4.713138e+06    2.857730e+06
13224.164062   -2.054056e+06    1.624522e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    1.867437e+06   -4.746126e+06    2.878688e+06
-1.195839e+05   -2.081042e+06    1.472030e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000   2.109059e+06   -5.047602e+06    2.938542e+06
-1.202835e+05   -1.849329e+06    1.847072e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000   1.647607e+06   -3.689882e+06    2.042273e+06
  417.019592   -1.201436e+06    1.671364e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    1.358743e+06   -3.303262e+06    1.944519e+06
 1658.200684   -1.316609e+06    1.339788e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    1.395223e+06   -3.361252e+06    1.966029e+06
-1.027537e+05   -1.351428e+06    1.227283e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000    1.661256e+06   -3.721140e+06    2.059885e+06
-1.082121e+05   -1.219397e+06    1.555895e+05       20.000000           0.000
    1.000000    1.009244e-10           0.000           0.000           0.000
```

---

Please advise.

Comment: Is there a prescribed rule as to what values in your matrix / array you should change?  This looks like arbitrary assignment to me and I can't see how smart scripting / indexing can be used without individually changing the elements yourself.

Comment: First of all thanks for editing the text of my question. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do as this is my first time. The rule of the text changing is that the following text:       0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000           0.000
       0.000           0.000      shall be inserted every 4 line

Comment: You're very welcome.  OK, what I mean to ask is what rules are you applying to your matrix in order to change the values?  I see that some of the values in your matrix are being set to 0.  What rule(s) are you applying so that you set these locations to 0?

Comment: The question is unclear. are you asking what language to use?

Comment: @george - My guess is `fortran` as seen in the tags, but I suppose any language that is open source / free could be used.  The OP said to use any technology that can be run on any platform.

Comment: The input file has FORTRAN77 format

Comment: @PerLindstrom - I wouldn't say this is in `fortran77` format, but it's more like a tab delimited text file with floating point numbers.  Do you have a preference as to what language you would like this to be done in?  Also, take a look at the previous question I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: use whatever language you are most comfortable with. If the answer is `none` I would advise using python as its easy to learn and likely already installed on your linux box

Comment: The question is if and/or how one can replace the first 7 values to 0.000 and repeat it 8 times skip one line and start over again

Comment: @PerLindstrom - Do you have any experience in programming? Are you familiar with any languages?

Comment: I have some very basic experiences and learned how to do some quick and dirty hack when needed. I'm using Fortran77, Scilab and Matlab etc.

Comment: I can suggest a method in MATLAB if that is acceptable.

Comment: That should be very nice.

Comment: @PerLindstrom - Alright.  Give me a few moments.  BTW, which version of MATLAB are you using?  Depending on what version you're using, I have to write my code differently as there are some differences in function availability / syntax between older and newer versions.

Comment: I was in fact intending to use SciLab or Octave. As I don't have Matlab Licenc on this machine. There will be a licence on the university but it is closed until Monday August 4

Comment: That's ok.  My solution should still work with Octave.

Comment: Sounds great to me :-) I'm right now trying on a solution by the use of the Gnumeric spreadsheet but it is just jamming up the computer.

Comment: @PerLindstrom - I have written a solution for you in MATLAB / Octave.  Mind you, I'm not sure how this will perform if you have such large amounts of numeric data.  For the test case that you have provided, this works fine.

Comment: Hi @PerLindstrom, why no use the GNU Linux's stream editor `see` for in-place changing texts of a file. For details `man sed`. And the command is available in Mac OS X also.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for you in MATLAB / Octave.  First we will use [`textread`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFtextread) to read in the actual data.  I see that your text data is uneven.  The first row has 7 elements while the next rows have 5 elements each.  `textread` will zeropad this and read in the data as a single matrix.  Columns 6 and 7 will thus have zeroes with the exception of the first row.  I then extract out the numerical data where we just skip over the first row and only grab the first 5 columns.

After this, I loop through the rows, setting the first row to zero, the second row with its first and second elements set to 0, and then I skip over the next two rows after that.  I repeat this process until we reach the end of the text file.  I save the first column and this new numeric data to a text file.  I will use [`dlmwrite`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFdlmwrite) to facilitate this writing.

As such, assuming that the input data is in `testData.txt`, I write the new file to `testOut.txt` with the above rule that we have just talked about.  As such:

```
%// Read in data and extract numeric data only
testData = textread('testData.txt');
numericData = testData(2:end,1:5);
count = 1;

%// From the first row until the last
while(count <= size(numericData,1))
    numericData(count,:) = 0; %// Set first row to zero
    %// Ensure we don't go out of bounds
    if (count + 1 > size(numericData,1))
        break;
    end
    numericData(count+1,1:2) = 0; %// Set first two elements of next row to zero
    count = count + 4; %// Skip over two rows
end

%// Save the file.  Write the first row first
dlmwrite('testOut.txt', testData(1,:), '\t');
%// Append on top of the file the modified numeric data
dlmwrite('testOut.txt', numericData, '-append', 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%.6e');
```

---

The output I get in this text file is:

```
13499   8   10  1   1   0   0
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    2.107339e+06    -5.031084e+06   2.923746e+06
1.525013e+04    -1.833509e+06   1.992212e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.855410e+06    -4.713138e+06   2.857730e+06
1.322416e+04    -2.054056e+06   1.624522e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.867437e+06    -4.746126e+06   2.878688e+06
-1.195839e+05   -2.081042e+06   1.472030e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    2.109059e+06    -5.047602e+06   2.938542e+06
-1.202835e+05   -1.849329e+06   1.847072e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.647607e+06    -3.689882e+06   2.042273e+06
4.170196e+02    -1.201436e+06   1.671364e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.358743e+06    -3.303262e+06   1.944519e+06
1.658201e+03    -1.316609e+06   1.339788e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.395223e+06    -3.361252e+06   1.966029e+06
-1.027537e+05   -1.351428e+06   1.227283e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    1.661256e+06    -3.721140e+06   2.059885e+06
-1.082121e+05   -1.219397e+06   1.555895e+05    2.000000e+01    0.000000e+00
1.000000e+00    1.009244e-10    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
```

---

Take note that this is a tab delimited file.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One successful solution on my problem is the following script , provided by Andreas de Blanche http://www.hv.se/en/research/researchers/alphabetically/andreas-de-blanche :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $start = time;

my $inputName = $ARGV[0];

if($inputName)
{
   print "\n   Converting file: $inputName\n";
   print "   Output file: $inputName.out.\n\n";
}
else
{
   print "\n   Please enter input filename on commandline\n";
   print "              ./script.pl <input.txt>\n";
   print "   Output file: <input.out>.\n\n";
   exit;
}


open INFILE, "<$inputName" or die $!;
open OUTFILE, ">$inputName.out" or die $!;

my $cardRow=33; #Each card is 33 rows long.
my $count=0;
my $row=0;


while (<INFILE>)
{
#   print "$row: $_"; 

   if($_=="")
   {
   }
   elsif($cardRow==33)
   {
      #print Reset counter $count
      $count=-1;
      $cardRow=0;

      #Just print line to outfile
      print OUTFILE "$_";
   }
   elsif($count==0) 
   {
      #These rows seems to always be identical
      print OUTFILE " 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00\n";
   }
   elsif($count==1) 
   {
      my $fragment =  substr $_, 32;
      print OUTFILE " 0.000000000E+00 0.000000000E+00$fragment";
   }
   elsif($count==2 || $count==3) 
   {
      #These rows should not be changed
      print OUTFILE "$_";
   }
   else
   {
      print "ERROR: This wrong sized subset!\n";
   }

   $count++;
   if($count==4)
   {
      #There are 4 rows in each subset (0-3)
      $count=0;
   }
   $cardRow++;
   $row++;
}


close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;

my $duration = time - $start;
print "   Execution time: $duration s\n";
```